# Best Loss function to use for Multiple Categories which have an implicit order

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function, multiclass-classification

I am wondering what options I have for loss functions when the task at hand is Multi-Class Classification, where the classes themselves have an **implicit order**, ranging from least popular (class 0) to most popular (class 11). The options I have thought of are the following:

1. Using regular Categorical Crossentropy Loss
2. Making the model a regression model based on the class number itself

Is there a categorical loss function which takes this implicit order between classes into account, or should I just try the two options listed above?

Comment: [Ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression)?

Comment: Is this available within tensorflow ?

Comment: A google search for "ordinal regression tensorflow" gives some seemingly relevant results, like [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-ordinal-logistic-regression-1afd0645e591).